# Choosing and using an IDE

Tags: c++, eclipse

I've been using Visual Studio 2010 for C++ development for a while but I'd like to move to an open source option. I'm considering using Eclipse C++. Are there any problems with it that I should know about? Also, I want to develop GUI applications. Presumably Eclipse allows this but I can't find any documentation on it (surprisingly)?

Can someone please point me in the right direction for starting with Eclipse?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: What is your reasoning for switching the IDE? Do you want to do cross-platform development?

Comment: See [this](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/tips/CPP_Dev_eclipse_CDT.aspx) for starting with eclipse.

Comment: Here is from the Netbeans home page, if Eclipse doesn't suit you, I have experience with Netbeans, which supports the following: NetBeans IDE 7.0

Develop desktop, mobile and web applications with Java, PHP, C/C++ and more.

Runs on Windows, Linux, Mac OS X and Solaris. NetBeans IDE is open-source and free.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was about to close this as a duplicate shopping question, but the GUI part is what stopped me.

You have two very good options:

1. Qt Creator: integrated version control, debugger support and Qt GUI editor.
2. Code::Blocks: integrated debugger, some plugins and a wxWidgets GUI editor.

Answer (score 1):

Netbeans is better and faster than Eclipse in coding C++. that's my personal opinion